# Solana React TypeError: this.wallet.signTransaction is not a function

Tags: reactjs, solana

Now I'm going to connect solana and React.js.
And I tried to get wallet like this.

```
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
....
function Header(props) {
 const wallet = useWallet();
    const initialize = async () => {
        const provider = await getProvider()
        const program = new Program(contractJson, programID, provider);
        console.log('program', program)
        try {
            /* interact with the program via rpc */
            await program.rpc.initialize({
                accounts: {
                    myOntology: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
                    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
                    rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
                    clock: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
                },
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Transaction error: ", err);
        }

    }
}
```

when I call initialize method, I got this error.
**TypeError: this.wallet.signTransaction is not a function**
So I've logged about wallet and signTransaction is null.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnstX.jpg)

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provider you pass into Program needs to incorporate your wallet

```
const wallet = useWallet();
const connection = new Connection('<devnet url here>')

const provider = new anchor.Provider(connection, wallet, anchor.Provider.defaultOptions()) 

const program = new Program(contractJson, programID, provider);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using an anchor rpc program method, so you need to invoke the `useAnchorWallet` method.

```
import { useAnchorWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";

const wallet = useAnchorWallet();
```

If you look at the `useAnchorWallet` method it contains an interface which expects a `Transaction` as an input:

```
signTransaction(transaction: Transaction): Promise<Transaction>;
```

The standard wallet adapter has the same method namespace but has a different interface:

```
signTransaction: SignerWalletAdapterProps['signTransaction'] | undefined;
```